# How do I prevent Paperclip from storing attachments in the spec folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, paperclip

Im busy testing Paperclip in an application that sends documents to another service. However, I noticed that during testing my **spec/documents** folder begins filling up with attachments from unit tests. I know this has something to do with my config, but I cant seem to figure out why it puts the files in this folder or how to prevent it from happening.

```
if Rails.env.production?
 Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!({
     ...
 })
elsif Rails.env.test?
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!({
   storage: :filesystem,
   url: "/test_attachments",
   path: ":rails_root/spec:url"
  })
else
   Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!({
     storage: :filesystem,
     url: "/uploads/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename",
     path: ":rails_root/public:url"
   })
end
```

Any thoughts? I was hoping there was some config option that would allow me to disable storage in the test environment but I haven't been able to find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell from the documentation, it suggests to remove the directory. It doesn't look like you can specify Paperclip avoid storage altogether.

See Documentation on Testing here https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#testing